# Issue with the function "digitise" from "survHE"

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I am trying to replicate the steps from a blog on survival modelling: https://healthdatacounts.com/2019/12/03/reconstructing-data-from-kaplan-meier-curves/

I work in R with the package "survHE" with the function "digitise"

When I run the code attached ("Code_Guyot") I get an error message when I try to run the "digitise" function: "Error in `[.data.frame`(pub.risk, , 5) : undefined columns selected".

---

```
#Read survival data
Guyot_data <- read.csv("Guyot_data_2.csv", header = TRUE)
head(Guyot_data)


#Determine which rows the upper and lower values of each interval are
find_interval_limits <- function(start_time,
                                 surv_time){
  
if (max(surv_time) > max(start_time))
stop("Intervals must span all survival times. Later interval missing.")
  
interval <- 1
end_time <- start_time[2]
upper <- NULL
  
for (i in seq_along(surv_time)){
    if (surv_time[i] >= end_time) {
      
      upper[interval] <- i - 1 
      interval <- interval + 1
      end_time <- start_time[interval + 1]
    } 
}
  
cbind(lower = c(1, upper + 1),
     upper = c(upper, length(surv_time)))
}


interval_limits <-
 find_interval_limits(start_time = c(0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60),
                      surv_time = Guyot_data$Time)

#We can then add this extraction date-specific values to the numbers at risk data take `enter code here from a table in the paper

Guyot_atrisk <- read.csv("Guyot_atrisk.csv", header = TRUE)
Guyot_atrisk[, c("lower", "upper")] <- interval_limits
head(Guyot_atrisk)

# required row number
Guyot_data <- cbind("k" = rownames(Guyot_data), Guyot_data)

# The arguments of digitise are file names of text file so we need to save these data `enter code here`first
write.table(Guyot_atrisk, file = "Guyot_atrisk.txt", row.names = FALSE)
write.table(Guyot_data, file = "Guyot_data.txt", row.names = FALSE)


#my code
surv.inp <- "Guyot_data.txt"
nrisk.inp <- "Guyot_atrisk.txt"
km_out <- "KMdata.txt"
ipd_out <- "IPDdata.txt"
digitise(surv.inp, nrisk.inp)
```

---

It looks like I have some issues with the lower and upper bound values for the file containing the number of patients at risk.

Did I do anything wrong? Where is the mistake?

At the link below you can fin the input files.

The *.csv files are the files where I have extracted survival data from the Kaplan Meier plot (I have used the radiotherapy arm data from the publication from "Guyot et al. BMC Medical Research Methodology 2012, 12:9").

The *.txt files are the input of the "digitise" function at the final stage of the calculation.

[Blockquote](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/a2c1sgp65lx2iay/AAC10iA1rvJTx76Dxlm32od8a?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

Can you open an issue on the `survHE` [GitHub repo](https://github.com/giabaio/survHE) - possibly including a link to the actual data so I can replicate the problem? (I am kind of swamped with a million things and, believe you me, I would much rather do *this*, than everything else!, so may not be immediate, but I can try and look at it!).